# Symmetric Mutual Authentication Case

Tags: authentication

I have an interesting question about mutual-authentication with a symmetric key. Is this scheme possible and secure? And is this scheme a mutual-authentication scheme?

```
Alice -------"Im Alice"--------> Bob 
      <---------E(R,K)----------
      ----------E(R+1,K)------->
```

I think it is secure, because Bob and Alice shares different messages (R+1 != R). And nobody else could read the symmetric key k, because only Alice and Bob shares it to encrypt and decrypt. But I don't know if it's possible to do the 1st step that says "Im Alice" without a R.

Do you know if it's possible?

Comment: Define R and K. Define 'secure'.

Comment: I think this should be on crypto.stackexchange.com instead of here.

Comment: R is a Random Number and K the symmetric key

Comment: But with your answer I know it's not secure because that I'ts always a E(R,K) sended. Alice doesn't know that is Bob talking, because E(R,K) could be send infinite times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer to your question: do not design your own protocol, it will not be secure.

Longer answer: it is not secure for general use. Problems off the top of my head:

1. Alice does not know she is talking to Bob. Anyone could replay an earlier challenge, and Alice would respond to it without knowing to whom she is talking. You might mitigate this in many ways, but your extremely non-detailed protocol doesn't define anything to mitigate it.
2. Bob doesn't really know it's Alice. You didn't include anything in your extremely limited protocol definition to ensure that responses cannot be replayed. If Bob sends the same R, Alice will send the same R+1. If the attacker intercepts all R messages and all R+1 messages, he can replay the R+1 ciphertext without ever knowing the plaintext.
3. This protocol does nothing to prevent a man in the middle. The attacker can intercept and forward all messages and will remain undetected.

Comment: Thaks atk. An R in the 1st message is something precious - I got it :) 
And it's completely necessary to add a "Nonce" to that kind of protocol works fine !

Comment: A nonce is not sufficient to shore up your protocol.  See point 1